# Is there any advantage in pulling 10?

Tags: pokemon-masters

In Pokemon Masters, there is the safe mechanic as in all Gatcha games, where you can pull 1 or 10 at the same time.

But usually, in these games theres advantages in pulling 10; something extra or a discount. But in pokemon masters, it looks like theres no advantages besides less menuing; which is bizzare.

So is there an advantage in pulling 10 in pokemon masters?

[image: Pokemon Masters]

Comment: The only real advantage is if you use the special offer 10-sync pull pair. This makes the 10th pull a guaranteed 5 star. It can only be done once and only with paid gems. Otherwise, it just saves time as per Robert's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current version of the game there is no advantage to pulling 10 sync pairs. They do it more as a convenience than a reward. In games like GungHo's puzzles and dragons you can only pull Rare egg machines one at a time and this is very tedious when pulling many times. Currently Dena is just making it easier to pull many pairs. They offer the same feature in the Exchange shop for pearls. You can exchange 1 or 10 at a time for the exact same equivalent price.